# migrating from Postgres to MonetDB

Tags: postgresql, database-migration, monetdb

I need to know how to migrate from Postgres to MonetDB. Postgres is getting slow and we are trying to change to Monet. Someone now if already exists a script or another thing to migrate to Monet?

exist something equivalent to plpgsql on MonetDB?
exist materialized view on MonetDB?

Comment: Are you sure that MonetDB will magically solve all your problems?

Comment: really, I don't think. We are trying others databases. I'm in charge of tests on column based DB and I picked monetDB.

Comment: If you want to fix a problem, don't create new problems. What's the performance problem you have? Maybe we can help.

Comment: If you want to test your load on columnar DBs in general - try this one: https://github.com/citusdata/cstore_fdw It is an extension for postgres to enable columnar stores. In general columnar stores are only good for particular analytical workloads and are horible for general OLTP loads.

Comment: @IgorRomanchenko for the record, monetdb does magically solve all problems.  it is a gandalf merlin potter to the millionth power

Answer (score 3):

The following booklet may be relevant to quickly identify some syntactic feature differences. https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/SQL_Dialects_Reference

And the citrus performance is covered in a blogpost
https://www.monetdb.org/content/citusdb-postgresql-column-store-vs-monetdb-tpc-h-shootout

Answer (score 1):

firstly: You can export data from postgres like:

```
 psql -h xxxxx -U xx -p xx -d postgres -c "copy (select * from db40.xxx) to '/tmp/xxx.csv' delimiter ';'"
```

secondly: You must replace the NULL like:

```
sed 's/\\N/NULL/g' xxx.csv >newxxx.csv
```

last: You can use this to copy data into monetdb like:

```
mclient -u monetdb -d voc -h 192.168.205.8 -p 50000 -s "COPY INTO newxxx from '/tmp/newxxx.csv' using delimiters ';';"
```